# Full Calendar append 'x' on end of event title display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am trying to make an 'x' appear on the end of an event, so that when a user clicks it, it deletes the event from display.

I am using the following code to do so:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.append( "<span class='closeon'>X</span>" );
        element.find(".closeon").click(function() {
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
        });
    }
```

However, the 'x' appears on the line below, like so:

[image: Event]
    ...

How can I make it so it displays the event all on one line?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prepend` instead `append`:

***css***:

```
.closeon { float: right; }
```

***js***:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    var e = element.prepend("<span class='closeon'>&#10005;</span>");

    e.children('.closeon')
       .attr('data-event-id', event._id) 
       .click( function() {
          var id = $(this).attr('data-event-id');
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',id);
       });            
}
```

[ http://jsfiddle.net/8fa0j9d8/ ]

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this same task in fullcalender 5?

Comment: @MeetGondaliya You need to use the eventDidMount hook: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks